# Running Chrome Webrtc Logs

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, rtcdatachannel

Due to some problem with failing Datachannel (onmessage stop working after 1 hour - approximately 1 GB data send), I was trying to get WebRTC logs on newest Chrome (57) for Windows.

I was trying with official instrction from https://webrtc.org/web-apis/chrome/

```
chrome.exe --enable-logging --vmodule=*/webrtc/*=2,*/libjingle/*=2,*=-2 --no-sandbox
```

And with redirected output

```
--user-data-dir=d:/ChromeRedirected
```

But without success.

I get chrome_debug.log but without any info from webrtc modules - have any one similar problem ? Are there any resolutions for that ?

Comment: It looks like it's "user-data-dir" that's not working. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Location is working and some logs are available but not for module which I want to get info from

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few weeks of frustration I have get one Mac from my friend and on it everything is working like a charm

Please note that you have to also set v level for entire chrome to get any logs

So correct command for Mac looks like below

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --enable-logging --v=4  --vmodule=*/webrtc/*=1
```

and then logs are posted to

```
~/Libraries/Application Support/Google/Chrome/chrome_debug.log
```

It looks like there is a bug in Windows version of chrome which doesn't let you to see any logs from WebRTC.

Comment: Still a problem in 2021 :-(